# for loop with same dataframe on both side of the operator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have defined 10 different DataFrames A06_df, A07_df , etc, which picks up six different data point inputs in a daily time series for a number of years. To be able to work with them I need to do some formatting operations such as

```
A07_df=A07_df.fillna(0)

A07_df[A07_df < 0] = 0

A07_df.columns = col # col is defined

A07_df['oil']=A07_df['oil']*24
A07_df['water']=A07_df['water']*24
A07_df['gas']=A07_df['gas']*24

A07_df['water_inj']=0
A07_df['gas_inj']=0
A07_df=A07_df[['oil', 'water', 'gas','gaslift', 'water_inj', 'gas_inj', 'bhp', 'whp']]
```

etc for a few more formatting operations

Is there a nice way to have a for loop or something so I don’t have to write each operation for each dataframe A06_df, A07_df, A08.... etc?

As an example, I have tried

```
list=[A06_df, A07_df, A08_df, A10_df, A11_df, A12_df, A13_df, A15_df, A18_df, A19_df]

for i in list:

      i=i.fillna(0)
```

But this does not do the trick.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: @tripleee: dataframes are a pandas thing.

Answer (score 0):

As `i.fillna()` returns a new object (an updated copy of your original dataframe), `i=i.fillna(0)` will update the content of `i`but not of the list content `A06_df, A07_df,...`.

I suggest you copy the updated content in a new list like this:

```py
list_raw = [A06_df, A07_df, A08_df, A10_df, A11_df, A12_df, A13_df, A15_df, A18_df, A19_df]

list_updated = []

for i in list_raw:

      i=i.fillna(0)
      # More code here
      list_updated.append(i)
```

To simplify your future processes I would recommend to use a dictionary of dataframes instead of a list of named variables.

```py
dfs = {}
dfs['A0'] = ...
dfs['A1'] = ...

dfs_updated = {}

for k,i in dfs.items():

      i=i.fillna(0)

      # More code here
      dfs_updated[k] = i
```